# I can't send SMS verification code on real device

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I am using Firebase Phone auth service. Sending sms via emulator, but when sending via real device, I get "unknown 17499" error. 2-3 days ago there was no such problem.My app is not yet in the store.

[image]

I tried adding SHA256 but it didn't solve it.

Comment: Did you tried anything on Firebase, like enabling PlayIntegrity or implementing AppCheck?

Comment: yes I tried but it didn't work.

Comment: As you have mentioned it was working earlier, trying to enable PlayIntegrity or implementing AppCheck might have broke the Auth backend. Make sure you have added the correct sha256 in the AppCheck section in Firebase as well.
As for step debugging add some dummy testing numbers and OTP in Phone Sign-In methods and check if that works.